# How do I prevent tsc from including browser types in the compliation

Tags: node.js, typescript-typings

I have a script that uses ts-node:

```
#!/usr/binenv ts-node

const top: number[] = [];
```

but `tsc` complains:

```
top3.ts(3,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'top'.
```

because apparently `top` is a global variable in browsers.

I've installed `@types/node` and my `tsconfig.json` reads:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "types": ["node"],
  }
}
```

so I can refer to node builtins like `process`.

How do I configure `tsc` so that it does not include browser builtins, but only pure ECMAScript + node.js builtins?